# The function of buttons is removed when moving to group box?

Tags: c#, function, button, groupbox

At the beginning, I had 5 buttons in a panel and they worked perfectly. 
For example,

```
private void btnFlipX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgBox.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
    imgBox.Refresh();
}
```

However, when I moved them to `groupbox`, they did not work anything. I clicked on a `button` in `groupbox` and there was anything in there (there is no code in them). For example,

```
private void btnFlipX_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Anyone can give me the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like VS just added a new event method for your automatically and named it btnFlipX_Click**_1** instead of btnFlipX_Click; Are you sure you are assigning the right event (Where the += is)

Comment: I just edit the event method  from btnFlipX_Click_1 to btnFlipX_Click and It worked. I understood. I'm kinda new to C# so you help me understand about event method. Thank you so much!